# (error) incompatible versions of android in intellij

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-virtual-device

hi when i try to run an android program in intellij i get the following error:

```
Error:android-validator: [myapp4] Incompatible version 16 of Android SDK Tools package. Min version is 19. Please, update it though SDK manager.
```

i dont have internet connection so i have added android SDK components manually (i have included several APIs as you can see in the following picture:
[image]
but when i created the project i didnt set any min version for intellij and when i try to run my project i use an emulator (which i defined in AVD manager).
[image]

i dont know what is the problem and by the way i can`t connect to internet so a usefull solution would not involve connection to internet.

Answer (score 0):

If you look carefully, the error message is talking about `Android SDK Tools`, not `Android SDK`. You should look for it inside your Android SDK Manager. There is a component named `Android SDK Tools`, that is what you need. You probably want to update everything available inside the "tools" folder too.

[image]

Comment: in my SDK manager, it says that these two files(Android SDK tools, Android SDK Platform-tools) are installed already

Comment: @user3593084 What are their version? The error message said it the SDK tools need to be at least version 19 or higher

Comment: i know it is version 16 (under the Rev. column it says 16), but my question is (i didnt specified anywhere that min version should be 19 ! and how can i change this setting to version 16 or higher??).